# SLF4J in distributable library, how to obtain Logger

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I want to distribute a lib relying on the `SLF4J` logger interface. What is the best practice way to obtain the logger which integrate nicely into any other project? Sorry for the unstructured question style, I'm still trying to figure out how all this stuff is glued together.

In other projects I always use this piece of code, because I want to obtain a custom logger:

```
private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory().getLogger(NAME_OF_APP);
```

If I create the class `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` and have it some other lib, does the therein defined factory get used even if I just call  `LoggerFactory.getLogger(NAME_OF_APP)` or is some default slf4j factory used?

I want the user to be able to use his own factory and logger, so which way is to perfere, and most of all why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do.

SLF4J is composed of two parts. First the API which you use in your lib to code your logging calls. And secondly the implementation which you use during your development to do logging, but DO NOT set as a dependency of the lib.

Because SLF4J looks for the implementations on the class path the developers using our lib can simple include any implementation they want. Sometimes is some quite strange ways :-) They can use a range of prebuilt implementations or code their own. It's up to them.

I don't think you need to do anything more than just use SLF4J's API as is.

Comment: Thanks, but then I don't quite understand where the difference is between calling `LoggerFactory.getLogger` and `LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory().getLogger`?

Comment: Without digging into the API - I've plenty of the first and none of the second. I would suspect that LoggerFactory.getLogger deals with that for you and you don't need to worry about it. Nor coding a factory unless you are doing something really odd.

Answer (score 2):

From http://slf4j.org/manual.html

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
    logger.info("Hello World");
  }
}
```

So, always use `LoggerFactory.getLogger(...)`.  The argument allow the logger backend to determine the behavior of the logger returned to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand what your scenario is.

But from my viewpoint, what you want is a distributed logging component.

A simple approach to do that is a socket appender. And a full feature component for distributed logging may like Facebook's scribe.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Logger`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/apidocs-0.7.7/com/jcabi/log/Logger.html) static wrapper from [jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/):

```
import com.jcabi.log.Logger;
public class MyLibraryClass {
  public void foo() {
    Logger.info(this, "some information");
  }
}
```

All logs will be sent through SLF4J.